# Whatsapp Automtion using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, whatsapp

i am trying to automate WhatsApp, following steps are to be done,problem is in point 4:

1. launch whatsapp.web
2. scan QR code:
3. search contact
4. clicke on the searched contact, tried the code but didn't show any output.
   folllowing is my code:

   `search_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/label').click() search_box_input=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]') search_box_input.send_keys('racpient name')`

after it how to click on searched contact?

5. tried code for clicking searched contact is :

   ```
   '
    target = "racipient"
    input('Press Enter after scanning QR Code...') 
    TargetXML = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = " {}"]'.format(target))
    TargetXML.click() '
   ```

6. image is attached,how to do step 2 (click on search contact) in labeled image[image: attached image]

Comment: What is the error message you get on Step 4?

Comment: Also, share the html if you can?